# perl variable not storing data outside block

Tags: perl

I have written below mention code to read a file and and storing data to array `@s_arr`.

But when I am trying to print that `@s_arr` array outside the block it shows nothing.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @s_arr;
my @err;
my %sort_h_1;

$fname = '/qv/Error.log';

open( IN, "<$fname" );

foreach $line ( <IN> ) {

    if ( $line =~ /CODE\+(\w{3})(\d{5})/ ) {
        $a = "$1$2";
        push @err, $a;
    }
}

close IN;

$prev  = "";
$count = 0;

my %hash;

foreach ( sort @err ) {

    if ( $prev ne $_ ) {

        if ( $count ) {
            $hash{$prev} = $count;
        }

        $prev  = $_;
        $count = 0;
    }

    $count++;
}

print Dumper \%hash;

printf( "%s:%d\n", $prev, $count ) if $count;

$hash{$prev} = $count;
my $c = 0;

print "Today Error Count\n";

foreach my $name ( sort { $hash{$b} <=> $hash{$a} } keys %hash ) {

    #printf "%-8s %s\n", $name, $hash{$name};
    #my %sort_h ;

    push @s_arr, $name;
    push @s_arr, $hash{$name};

    #$sort_h{$name} = $hash{$name} ;
    #print Dumper \%sort_h ;
    #print Dumper \@s_arr ;

    $c++;

    if ( $c eq 30 ) {
        exit;
    }
}

print Dumper \@s_arr;    #  It's showing nothing
```

Comment: Please indent the code nicely when you post questions, if you expect people to read through it.  As you nicely declare `@s_arr` on top a conceivable reason would be that there is actually nothing in it, but `Dumper`'s print of `%hash` indicates otherwise. So ... does your `$c` actually get to be equal `30` by any chance, so the program quietly `exit`s?  (Btw, should use `==` there.)

Answer (score 4):

You are calling [`exit`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html) inside of your `foreach` loop. That makes the program stop, and the `print Dumper @s_arr` is never reached.

To break out of a loop you need to use [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html).

```
foreach my $name ( sort ...  ) {

    # ...

    $c++;

    last if $c == 30; # break out of the loop when $c reaches 30

}
```

I used the *postfix* variant of `if` here because that makes it way easier to read. Also note that [as zdim pointed out above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407327/perl-varibale-not-storing-data-outside-block/43407708#comment73874304_43407327), you should use the numerical equality check `==` when checking for numbers. `eq` is for strings.

Comment: @DineshSharma please see [ask] to learn what to do when someone answers your question.